# Get single record for every ID from union

Tags: sql, postgresql

I store 100s of ad texts in one table, they can either be scheduled or a default one. I want to return a single record for each cust_id.

I have two select sql queries- first one checks if the a customer has a scheduled text and second gets the default.

```
SELECT
            id, cust_id
        FROM
            texts
        WHERE
            over18 = FALSE
            AND now()
            BETWEEN ad_start_date
            AND ad_end_date)
    UNION ALL (
        SELECT
            id, cust_id
        FROM
            texts
        WHERE
            over18 = FALSE
            AND texts.default = TRUE
        ORDER BY
            created_at DESC)
```

The problem is that the second select returns more than one record for each cust_id.

Comment: What about `SELECT DISTINCT id, cust_id` inside of the UNION ALL?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a set based result then you should use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.
You can read more about their differences [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/queries-union.html). Another way would be using the `DISTINCT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cust_id) id, cust_id
FROM texts
WHERE over18 = FALSE AND
      (now() BETWEEN ad_start_date AND ad_end_date OR
       texts.default = TRUE
      )
ORDER BY cust_id,
         ( now() BETWEEN ad_start_date AND ad_end_date )::int desc,
         created_at DESC;
```